# Angular: ErrorInterceptor not beeing called

Tags: angular, interceptor

I wrote an error interceptor for my angular app so that the user is routed to the login page if a 401 is detected.

Strange thing is that the error block is never called. Only the entry and success console log entry is in my console.

Any idea what might be wrong?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        console.log('interceptor called');

        return next.handle(req).do(event => {
            console.log('interceptor in success', event);
        }, err => {

            console.log('interceptor in error', err);

            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {

                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        });
    }
}


export const errorInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true,
};
```

The interceptor is integrated in my app module:

```
providers: [
    ...
    errorInterceptorProvider
  ],
```

Comment: could you add a complete example please? This doesn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work see https://plnkr.co/edit/mQnrJQarp4wRaohKNzre?p=preview

Another option is using `catch` operator:

```typescript
...
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('interceptor called');

    return next.handle(req)
      .do(event => {
        console.log('interceptor in success', event)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('interceptor in error', err);
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        return Observable.throw(err);
        // or return Observable.empty();
      })
      .finally(() => {
        console.log('finally');
      });
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nkgflfss4TiIEkOKK5hg?p=preview)**

Comment: mhh... again error is not called. What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you create example somewhere to reproduce it?